# eyes rig : rotation issue in blender

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, bones, parent

Hello i have been following this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvEuroezCng&t=464s

to make eyes and add movement to it

everything is going good till 3:45secconds

when i tried to rotate as he mentioned by clicklon on `"r -90"`

[image]

instead of getting this

[image]

im getting something like this

im not sure what possibly could have gone wrong
tried this several time made sure that i didnt miss any step

but still couldn't figure out why The results is totally different

Comment: hello please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/c894af7c05c94993a224eb2801b45966

Comment: done please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine, only press <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>-90</kbd> if you are in side view, if you are not, press <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>-90</kbd> to precise the rotation angle, otherwise the rotation will happen according to your current view, which will give the unexpected result you show.